# getting the read receipt

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I am using `javamail` for sending emails. My requirement is to get read receipt from the recipient.

So far from my search on the net I have come across to some third party services which uses Images for this purpose. One drawback I have seen in those services is that in `gmail` we have to click on display image to open the images, and if user doesn't click on it then we can't get the read receipt from user even if he has read the mail.

So my question is what are the other ways to get read receipt. Without using third party services.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Downvoter Reason for downvoting will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no reliable way to do that, mostly because it's a privacy issue. You can ask for a [Message Disposition Notification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Return_receipt), but at best the client will ask the recipient whether to send a return receipt. As you know, you can also embed an image that will get loaded when a message is viewed as HTML, but (1) some people will still view plain text instead of HTML, and (2) image loading is blocked by most HTML mail programs specifically to prevent what you're trying to do.